# AS3 Error 1009 when Debugging

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to create a game over screen for my space ship game, when player's shields reach 0 it goes to game over screen and stop the gameplay. The game over screen is working, but I can't stop the gameplay. I tried to set the Ship to null when player's shields reach 0 but I got error 1009. And all the gameplay objects (Ship, Enemy...) will loaded to the stage when "public function fGameStart(evt: Event): void {" executes, is there a way that I can stop this function from running when game over? Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
public class Engine extends MovieClip {
    private var preloader: ThePreloader;

    public function Engine() {
        stage.addEventListener("gameSTART", fGameStart);
        stage.addEventListener("gameOVER", fGameOver);
    }

    private var numStars: int = 80;
    public static var enemyList: Array = new Array();
    private var ourShip: Ship;

    public function fGameStart(evt: Event): void {

        ourShip = new Ship(stage);
        ourShip.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        ourShip.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
        ourShip.addEventListener("hit", shipHit, false, 0, true);
        stage.addChild(ourShip);

        for (var i: int = 0; i < numStars; i++) {
            stage.addChildAt(new Star(stage), stage.getChildIndex(ourShip));
        }

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);

        function loop(e: Event): void {

            if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) == 5) {
                var enemy: Stinger = new Stinger(stage, ourShip);
                enemy.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removeEnemy, false, 0, true);
                enemy.addEventListener("killed", enemyKilled, false, 0, true);
                enemyList.push(enemy);
                stage.addChild(enemy);
            }

            else if (Math.floor(Math.random() * 80) == 5) {
                var enemy2: Stinger2 = new Stinger2(stage, ourShip);
                enemy2.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removeEnemy, false, 0, true);
                enemy2.addEventListener("killed", enemyKilled, false, 0, true);
                enemyList.push(enemy2);
                stage.addChild(enemy2);
            }
        }
    }

    public function fGameOver(e: Event) {
        gotoAndStop(4);
        ourShip = null;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point setting the `ourShip` variable to `null`. It will not remove the `DisplayObject` from the `stage`, or remove it from memory. In fact the very reason you get this error is you setting it to `null`.

What you need to do is stop the `loop` function from triggering.

```
public function fGameOver(e: Event) {
    gotoAndStop(4);
    //ourShip = null;
    stage.removeChild(ourShip);
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
}
```

also setting a weak reference for you listener might be a bad idea here

```
//addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);
//why not:
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
```

Comment: If the function "public function fGameStart(evt: Event):" contains other gameplay objects, how do I remove the entire function as well? I tried 
"removeEventListener("gameSTART", GameStart);" but it didn't works.

Comment: you cannot remove functions, they are garbage collected when possible/flash feels like it

Comment: if you are asking how to stop a listener function from triggering then that is how you do it yes, but you are missing a "f"